# Filter RDF file using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am quite new to SPARQL and not sure that I am using it correctly, but I would like to use it to filter the rdf file - produce rdf file that contains only the parts of the graph that meet some conditions.

Let's say I have some rdf file containing triples:

```
id1 <http://xx.com/address> ids1
id1 <http://xx.com/name> John
id1 <http://xx.com/surname> Doe

ids1 <http://xx.com/street> Steep
ids1 <http://xx.com/number> 32

id2 <http://xx.com/address> ids2
id2 <http://xx.com/name> John
id2 <http://xx.com/surname> Dow

ids2 <http://xx.com/street> Flat
ids2 <http://xx.com/number> 32
```

And I would want to use sparql to produce rdf file containing only the part for surname Doe:

```
id1 <http://xx.com/address>ids1
id1 <http://xx.com/name> John
id1 <http://xx.com/surname> Doe

ids1 <http://xx.com/street> Steep
ids1 <http://xx.com/number> 32
```

But the first attempt only produces the triples for Doe, but not the address:

```
PREFIX xx: <http://xx.com/>

CONSTRUCT {
   ?s ?p ?o
}
WHERE {
     ?s ?p ?o .
     ?s xx:surname ?surname .
  FILTER(?surname = 'Doe')
}
```

Could you please tell me, what should I add to include also the subnodes and the parent nodes of those which fulfil the condition?

Comment: that does only work (efficiently) if you know the max depth/diameter and maybe even the structure of the graph. In your example indeed you know the structure, thus, you could simply append the missing triple patterns, or not? I mean, you know that `?o` could potentially have more data (like the address details), so you could use `OPTIONAL {?o ?p2 ?o2}`

Comment: the issue is more when there is more data attached, e.g. to `?o2` and then ... you get the idea. Also what about incoming edges. Do they also belong to the subgraph of interest?

Comment: Great, so when I did something like

    PREFIX xx: <http://xx.com/>

    CONSTRUCT {
      ?s ?p ?o .
       ?o ?p2 ?o2
    }
    WHERE {
     ?s ?p ?o .
     ?s xx:surname ?surname .
     FILTER(?surname = 'Doe') .
     OPTIONAL {?o ?p2 ?o2}
    }


it worked. I actually know the complete structure of the graph, so I guess I am ok. I don't understand the part with incoming edges though. Anyway, thanks a lot!